# Der Plural Teste

Tags: dialect, grammatical-number

Ich habe heute zum ersten Mal den Plural *Teste* gelesen. Nachdem ich eine Schülerin voreilig korrigiert hatte, musste ich feststellen, dass er tatsächlich im [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Test) steht. Ich kann mich nicht entsinnen, diese Form je gehört zu haben. Dabei bin ich nun schon weit in Deutschland und Österreich herumgekommen!

Wo ist die Form verbreitet?
Ist sie neu?

Answer (score 6):

Nein, das steht in meinem Rechtschreib-Lexikon von 1973 auch schon so, und ist auch plausibel, wenn man es mit Attest, Testat und ähnlichen Wörtern vergleicht. Dass inzwischen die gleiche Pluralform wie im Englischen die Oberhand gewonnen hat, wundert mich nicht.

Comment: Das ist hochinteressant! Eine Linguistin hier hat viele Fälle erforscht, in denen Plurale für Fremdwörter sich nach dem Muster Pizzas->Pizzen verschoben. Ich ging davon aus, der Plural mit s sei auch hier älter. Ist womöglich das Gegenteil der Fall? Nun da ich länger nachdenke, scheint es mir, als seien früher statt Test andere Vokabeln verwendet worden.

Comment: "Test" hat aber mit "Attest" und "Testat" etymologisch nichts zu tun.

Answer (score 5):

Es handelt sich wohl (wie so oft) um regionale Unterschiede, die in einem komplexen Zusammenhang mit der Sprachgeschichte stehen.

Der Plural auf *-s* ist typisch im Norddeutschen. Dem Süddeutschen ist er ursprünglich fremd. Im Schweizerdeutschen (als Beispiel für eine vom Norddeutschen relativ wenig beeinflusste Sprachform) ist bei vielen bis heute überhaupt keine Plural auf *-s* anzutreffen, ausser höchstens in offensichtlichen Fremdwörtern aus dem Englischen. Also heisst es dann:

- ei Test/zwe Test(e)
- eis Auto/zwöü Auto
- ei Ballon/zwe Ballön
- ei Park/zwe Pärk

Das moderne Hochdeutsch entwickelt sich seit dem 19. Jahrhundert unter norddeutschem Einfluss. Diese Entwicklung begann mit dem Aufstieg Preussens zur führenden politischen Macht, wurde verstärkt durch die aufkommenden Massenmedien, und war nach der Auf‌lösung Preussens schon zum Selbstläufer geworden.

Der norddeutsche Einfluss äussert sich nicht nur in der Aussprache, wo norddeutsche Eigenheiten wie etwa die Aspirierung von /p t k/ sich verbreitet haben (daher dünkt uns heute der Ausspracheunterschied zwischen «deutsch» und «teutsch» derart gross, dass wir gar nicht mehr nachvollziehen können, wie eine Schwankung dazwischen möglich war), sondern eben auch in Gebieten wie der Deklination, wo das norddeutsche Plural-*s* zunehmende an Raum gewonnen hat.

Comment: Damit passt auch, dass der mittelalterliche Test auch als Dest bekannt war ;)

Comment: Das stimmt haargenau, vgl. [test (DWB)](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=dest).

Answer (score 1):

Die Behauptung, dass das Wort Test erst im 20. Jahrhundert in den deutschen Sprachraum "eingewandert" sei, kann man so nicht stehen lassen.

Schon im Mittelhochdeutschen kannte man den [Test](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GD01703#XGD01703), nämlich den Schmelztiegel mit dem man die Reinheit von Silber prüfte. Der Plural war damals schon *teste*.

> Und swaz wâzes der Test
>   wider êrste gewinnet,
>   des Gesmackes ime zerinnet
>   nimmer mêre fürbaz.
>   <sup>[Heinrich vom Türlein 1515](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GD01703#XGD01703)</sup>

Auch das englische *[test](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=test)* hat diese Etymologie. Es hat aber dort schon im 16. Jahrhundert einen Bedeutungswandel hin zu einem *Test* als allgemeines Prüfverfahren erhalten.

Im Deutschen wurde diese Bedeutung erst Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts übernommen. Erst mit der (fälschlichen ?) Annahme, es handele sich um ein gänzlich neues Lehnwort aus dem Englischen hat sich auch die englische Pluralbildung *Tests* hier eingebürgert.

Comment: Das ist nicht dasselbe Wort. Das Wort, das du meinst bezeichnet einen Schmelztiegel, keine Prüfung. Der etymologische Zusammenhang besteht natürlich, aber Schmelztiegel und Prüfung sind nicht dasselbe. Das ist, wie wenn man behaupten würde, *der Schild, pl: die Schilde* (Verteidigungswaffe) und *das Schild, pl: die Schilder* (Etikett, Plakette) wären dasselbe Wort.

Comment: In der Bedeutung "Schmelztiegel" ist "Test" in der Tat eine alte (mittelhochdeutsche) Entlehnung aus dem Altfranzösischen. In der Bedeutung "Prüfung" ist "Test" eine moderne Entlehnung aus dem Englischen. Es sind historisch gesehen zwei verschiedene Wörter gleichen Ursprungs.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: wie in meiner Antwort verlinkt, aber offenbar nicht gelesen: https://www.etymonline.com/word/test, da steht allerhand zur Etymologie des **englischen** *test*.

Comment: @fdb: genau. Es ist das gleiche Wort aber mit einem Bedeutungswandel, der vom Englischen stammend nun auch im Deutschen übernommen wurde. Es wundert also nicht so sehr, wenn auch die ursprüngliche Wortgrammatik erhalten blieb.

Answer (score 0):

Die Behauptung von [mach](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/44263/1487) die Form »die Tests« wäre dem Süddeutschen ursprünglich fremd gewesen, ist meiner Meinung nach nicht richtig.

Laut Herkunftswörterbuch des Duden ist das Wort »Test« erst Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts in die deutsche Sprache eingewandert, und zwar aus dem Englischen. Dorthin kam es aus der französischen Sprache, wo man das Wort offenbar als Bezeichnung für einen irdenen Alchimistentiegel verwendet hat, der seinerseits seinen Namen vom lateinischen *testum* (Geschirr) hat.

Jedenfalls gibt es dieses Wort erst seit rund 100 Jahren in er deutschen Sprache, was auch gut mit diesem [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Test%2CTests%2CTeste&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTests%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTeste%3B%2Cc0) übereinstimmt:

[image]

Im 19.Jahrhundert war zwar die Form »die Tests« im Süddeutschen tatsächlich fremd, aber das lag eben daran, dass das ganze Lexem im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum fremd war.

Ich habe leider keine wirklich aussagekräftigen Belege für den süddeutschen Sprachraum vor 1975, aber sehr wohl für 1975. Da hilft mir nämlich ein altes Schulbuch von mir:

Im Österreichischen Wörterbuch, 34. Auflage aus dem Jahr 1975 steht nämlich:

> **Test** der, -(e)s/-s: Ein Verfahren zur Prüfung des Intelligenz, der Berufseignung u. ä.

Demnach war der einzige in Österreich erlaubte Plural damals »die Tests«. Die Form »die Teste« gab es damals nicht, und das deckt sich auch sehr gut mit meiner Erinnerung.

Selbes Werk (ÖWB), diesmal aber die 39. Auflage aus dem Jahr 2001:

> **Test** der, -(e)s/-s (-e): Versuch, experimentelle Untersuchung; ein Verfahren zur Prüfung des Intelligenz, der Berufseignung, der Leistung, zur Materialprüfung uÄ

Im Jahr 2001 existierte also schon die Form »die Teste« als Nebenform zu »die Tests«, allerdings als Ausnahme.

---

<sub>Ab hier Off-topic:</sub>

<sub>Das Wort »Test« hat übrigens nichts mit »Testament«, »Attest« oder »Testat« zu tun. Diese Wörter gehen auf das kirchenlateinische *testamentum* zurück. Dieses Wort stammt wiederum vom lateinischen *testari* (bezeugen) bzw von *testis* (Zeuge) ab, und ist mit dem Wort Testikel (Hoden) verwandt. Bei den Hebräern war es nämlich üblich, etwas zu bezeugen, indem man auf seine Hoden schwörte und beim Schwur seine Hand an dieses Organ hielt. Dieser Brauch hielt sich im Libanon bis ins 19. Jahrhundert, und die Bibelstelle *1.Mose 24 2* belegt das auch recht gut:</sub>

<sub>Übersetzung [Hoffnung für alle](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/HFA/1.Mose24):</sub>

> <sub>Eines Tages sagte Abraham zu seinem Hausverwalter, der sein ältester Knecht war: »Als Zeichen des Schwures **lege die Hand auf meinen Unterleib**«</sub>

<sub>Übersetzung [Gute Nachricht Bibel](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/GNB/1.Mose24):</sub>

> <sub>Eines Tages sagte er zu seinem ältesten Knecht, der seinen ganzen Besitz verwaltete: »**Leg deine Hand zwischen meine Beine**«</sub>

<sub>(Andere Übersetzungen lassen diese Stelle entweder ganz aus, oder umschrieben sie mit »lege die Hand unter meine Hüfte«.)</sub>

Comment: Schon in vorklassischem Latein (Plautus usw.) hat „testis“ beide Bedeutungen („Zeuge“ und „Hode“). Dies hat also nichts mit jüdischem oder christlichem Gebrauch zu tun.

Comment: @fdb: Stimmt schon. Ich wollte mit der Bibelstelle nur die Existenz dieses Zusammenhangs belegen, den es in abgewandelter Form bei einem anderen Wort ja auch im Deutschen gibt (»Ich bin **Zeuge** im Prozess« und »Ich **zeuge** ein Kind«. bzw. auch *Zeug, Zeugnis, Erzeugnis*)